# How can I use Babel instead of SWC in "next build"?

Tags: next.js

I can't use SWC in my projects, because of security reasons. Our company has an npm mirror and our applications builds in environment where there is no internet access (in build time it has access only for corporate services, like npm mirror). When I trying to install SWC from our npm mirror (npm install) at some point it's dependency (package "fibers") trying to start "node-gyp rebuild" command. This command is required python 3, node headers (bunch of .h files), make, and Visual C++ build tools or Visual Studio installed in build environment and of course fails with error (npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild). And again for some corporate security reasons I can't install Visual Studio or Visual C++ build tools because they trying to download some stuff from internet (I didn't found standalone versions for this).
Nevermind. There are restrictions due to which I cannot use SWC compiler. And I think that I'm not the only one. So I trying to find a way to use Babel instead of SWC. And for "next dev" command I did it. But in "next build" time next.js trying to find installed SWC and patch my package-lock.json file if didn't find it. And it fails to patch a package-lock.json file with this error:

```
- warn Attempted to load @next/swc-win32-x64-gnu, but it was not installed
- warn Attempted to load @next/swc-win32-x64-msvc, but it was not installed
- warn Found lockfile missing swc dependencies, patching...
- error Failed to patch lockfile, please try uninstalling and reinstalling next in this workspace
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (C:\Work\next-test\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\undici\index.js:1:26669)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async fetchPkgInfo (C:\Work\next-test\node_modules\next\dist\lib\patch-incorrect-lockfile.js:65:17)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async patchIncorrectLockfile (C:\Work\next-test\node_modules\next\dist\lib\patch-incorrect-lockfile.js:161:26) {
  cause: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
      at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1530:34)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:520:28)
      at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:944:8)
      at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:725:12) {
    code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'
  }
}
- error Failed to load SWC binary for win32/x64, see more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc
- info Creating an optimized production build
```

So... Only for build mode Next.js trying to download SWC binary from internet. Interesting and strange.

The question is: how can I prevent Next.js attempts to download files and just make it use already installed Babel like in dev mode?

I created .babelrc file in the root of my project:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions"]
}
```

Also, according to the documentation I created a next.config.js file in the root of my project:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  swcMinify: false
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

And here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "next-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^13.4.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions": "^7.22.5",
    "@types/node": "20.3.2",
    "@types/react": "18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.13",
    "typescript": "^5.1.5"
  }
}
```

It did work for "next dev", but didn't work for "next build".